# Setting Window Icon Using GLFW (LWJGL 3)

Tags: java, lwjgl, glfw

What's the best, cross platform, way of setting the window icon using LWJGL 3?

I have a PNG image and would like to set it to the icon present in my dock (OS X) or the application bar (Linux).

Comment: I'm surprised that this hasn't been asked before.

Comment: You could also use a jar bundler to create a .app and .exe with your icon.

Comment: Now that LWJGL3 uses GLFW for window management, it is currently impossible to set the window icon directly with LWJGL. However, it is being worked on and will probably [come in GLFW 3.2](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/453).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They added it to build 79, the method is called: glfwSetWindowIcon(long window, Buffer images);

Answer (score 2):

I have found an answer!!! After searching far and wide through the depths of the internet, I have found the following method. It works perfectly!

```
    public void setIcon(String path) throws Exception{
    IntBuffer w = memAllocInt(1);
    IntBuffer h = memAllocInt(1);
    IntBuffer comp = memAllocInt(1);

    // Icons
            {
                ByteBuffer icon16;
                ByteBuffer icon32;
                try {
                    icon16 = ioResourceToByteBuffer(path, 2048);
                    icon32 = ioResourceToByteBuffer(path, 4096);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

                try ( GLFWImage.Buffer icons = GLFWImage.malloc(2) ) {
                    ByteBuffer pixels16 = STBImage.stbi_load_from_memory(icon16, w, h, comp, 4);
                    icons
                        .position(0)
                        .width(w.get(0))
                        .height(h.get(0))
                        .pixels(pixels16);

                    ByteBuffer pixels32 = STBImage.stbi_load_from_memory(icon32, w, h, comp, 4);
                    icons
                        .position(1)
                        .width(w.get(0))
                        .height(h.get(0))
                        .pixels(pixels32);

                    icons.position(0);
                    glfwSetWindowIcon(window, icons);

                    STBImage.stbi_image_free(pixels32);
                    STBImage.stbi_image_free(pixels16);
                }
            }

            memFree(comp);
            memFree(h);
            memFree(w);

}
```

And the "ioResourceToByteBuffer" method is in a class that contains this:

```
    private static ByteBuffer resizeBuffer(ByteBuffer buffer, int newCapacity) {
    ByteBuffer newBuffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(newCapacity);
    buffer.flip();
    newBuffer.put(buffer);
    return newBuffer;
}

/**
 * Reads the specified resource and returns the raw data as a ByteBuffer.
 *
 * @param resource   the resource to read
 * @param bufferSize the initial buffer size
 *
 * @return the resource data
 *
 * @throws IOException if an IO error occurs
 */
public static ByteBuffer ioResourceToByteBuffer(String resource, int bufferSize) throws IOException {
    ByteBuffer buffer;

    Path path = Paths.get(resource);
    if ( Files.isReadable(path) ) {
        try (SeekableByteChannel fc = Files.newByteChannel(path)) {
            buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer((int)fc.size() + 1);
            while ( fc.read(buffer) != -1 ) ;
        }
    } else {
        try (
            InputStream source = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resource);
            ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(source)
        ) {
            buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(bufferSize);

            while ( true ) {
                int bytes = rbc.read(buffer);
                if ( bytes == -1 )
                    break;
                if ( buffer.remaining() == 0 )
                    buffer = resizeBuffer(buffer, buffer.capacity() * 2);
            }
        }
    }

    buffer.flip();
    return buffer;
}
```